# "Idiom" and "idiot"

Tags: etymology

The words *idiom* and *idiot* differ only in the final letters: *t* and *m*. So I was wondering - do these words have a common root? If so, how have the *t* and *m* changed this root?

Comment: NOAD traces both back to Gr *idios* 'own, private', but the difference seems to stem to Gr derivatives of this.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect this may be general reference, but from the OED:

Etymology of *idiot*:

> ancient Greek ἰδιώτης private person, person without professional knowledge, layman, ignorant, ill-informed person, in Hellenistic Greek also common man, plebeian < ἴδιος private, own, peculiar (see idio- comb. form) + -ώτης -ote suffix

Etymology of idiom:

> Hellenistic Greek ἰδίωμα peculiarity, property, peculiarity of style, form of language peculiar to a particular individual < ancient Greek ἰδιοῦσθαι to make one's own, to appropriate ( < ἴδιος own, private, peculiar: see idio- comb. form) + -μα (see -oma comb. form).

So it appears that they share a very distant root (idio-) but their meanings would have been distinct even in ancient Greece by virtue of the endings.

Comment: If you came up with that information by looking it up on-line, then, yes, it is general reference.

Comment: @Mitch: the OED is only available (online) by subscription, so it's a bit harsh to call it general reference.

Comment: @Tim: The etymology is available for all here: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=idiot&allowed_in_frame=0